# uploaded sample data after the magento-1.9 installation, godaddy VPS

Tags: database, error

There has been an error processing your request
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'dev_bechnus'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Trace:

```
0 /home/dev/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(109): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
1 /home/dev/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(320): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
2 /home/dev/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(460): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
3 /home/dev/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
4 /home/dev/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
5 /home/dev/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(169): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
6 /home/dev/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
7 /home/dev/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
8 /home/dev/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
9 /home/dev/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(335): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
10 /home/dev/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(360): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
11 /home/dev/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(134): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->getReadConnection()
12 /home/dev/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1348): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->__construct(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
13 /home/dev/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1380): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('core_resource/w...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
14 /home/dev/public_html/app/Mage.php(491): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
15 /home/dev/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(208): Mage::getResourceModel('core/website_co...', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
16 /home/dev/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(213): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getResourceCollection()
17 /home/dev/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(608): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getCollection()
18 /home/dev/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(466): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()
19 /home/dev/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('', 'store')
20 /home/dev/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
21 /home/dev/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
22 {main}
```

Answer (score 2):

Database user that your are using does not having the rights on the database.You can change the database user and its password in `app->etc->local.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Check your local.xml (`app/etc/local.xml`)

```
[...]
<default_setup>
   <connection>
      <host><![CDATA[##db host##]]></host>
      <username><![CDATA[##username##]]></username>
      <password><![CDATA[##password##]]></password>
      <dbname><![CDATA[##dbname##]]></dbname>
      <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
      <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
      <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
      <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
      <active>1</active>
   </connection>
</default_setup>
[...]
```

and check if you have entered the correct data in the fields `host`(usually localhost), `username`, `password`, `dbname`. After changing the data to the correct ones, clear you cache `var/cache/` to make sure there is no older version of you local.xml in the cache.

After these steps, go to the frontend and voilá your shop should run.

hope that helps.

cheers